# Ted's explanation for the 3rd argument of ListCorrelate doesn't apply to the {1, -1} case?

Tags: functions

I was reading [*Ted Ersek*'s explanation for the usage of `ListCorrelate`](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_L-O_4.html)(.nb version can be found [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4557/)) and noticed something confusing. It's the third example of **Specifying the "overhang" using {$K_L$, $K_R$}** section:

[image]

You may think that it's a typo at first glance, but the output is really correct. Just try it yourself:

```
{{a1, a2, a3, a4, 0, 0}, {0, a1, a2, a3, a4, 0}, {0, 0, a1, a2, a3, 
   a4}, {a4, 0, 0, a1, a2, a3}, {a3, a4, 0, 0, a1, a2}, {a2, a3, a4, 
   0, 0, a1}, {a1, a2, a3, a4, 0, 0}, {0, a1, a2, a3, a4, 0}, {0, 0, 
   a1, a2, a3, a4}}.{{b1}, {b2}, {b3}, {b4}, {b5}, {b6}}
Flatten[%] === ListCorrelate[{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6}, {1, -1}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

The other 3 examples do follow the statement though.

So Ted's theory is simply incomplete but he didn't notice? Or there's some deeper reason (in compatible changes between versions etc.)?

Comment: Is it possible to understand `{{b1}, {b2}, {b3}, {b4}, {b5}, {b6}}` as `{b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6}`?

Comment: @Tangshutao I think it's better not to. As far as I understand, instead of using concepts like "row", "column" etc. _Mathematica_ uses `Level` of lists (`Dimensions`?) when discussing matrices, which leads to a rule that is a little different from what's usually used in our Linear Algebra text book. `Dot` of two lists are the match of the last dimension of the former list and the first dimension of the latter list, so `{a, b, c} . {x, y, z}` becomes valid, which in our text book should be written as `{a, b, c} . {{x}, {y}, {z}}` .

Comment: @Tangshutao And I just noticed that in fact the rule used by _Mathematica_ is just consistent with the rule used by tensor notation. If you've ever learned about the basic tensor notation in any course, just recall it and you'll find the rule of `Dot` no longer that hard to understand!

Comment: Dear xzczd, Thanks sincerely! I didn't learn about the basic `tensor notation` and I will read some book about it.

Comment: @Tangshutao You're welcome, without answering your question, I won't have noticed the consistency today. 教学相长 :D

Comment: Related: [(58928)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58928/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that `False` is on his own web page indicates against this being a change between versions but rather something he failed to notice.

Following his equivalence we also have the last kernel element (`a4`) in the last place in the third row of the left matrix, an indeed that matches the actual output:

```
m = NestList[RotateRight, {a1, a2, a3, a4, 0, 0}, 2]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  \text{a1} & \text{a2} & \text{a3} & \text{a4} & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & \text{a1} & \text{a2} & \text{a3} & \text{a4} & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & \text{a1} & \text{a2} & \text{a3} & \text{a4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
ListCorrelate[{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6}, {1, -1}]

% === m.{b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6}
```

> ```
> {a1 b1 + a2 b2 + a3 b3 + a4 b4,
>  a1 b2 + a2 b3 + a3 b4 + a4 b5, 
>  a1 b3 + a2 b4 + a3 b5 + a4 b6}
>
> True
> ```

Comment: It looks like I did understand what ListCorrelate does with the third argument, but in that example above, I didn't use the right way of rotating the kernel. I wrote that a long time ago. I have to speculate that I didn't notice that the comparison returned False. I think I should use Mr. Wizard's way of rotating the kernel. When I make that change I will credit Mr. Wizard.

Comment: @TedErsek I did not think you were maintaining that page any longer.  (Last updated May 16, 2004 I believe?)  I am pleased to hear that you seem to be considering it.  I learned a great deal from your Tips and Tricks at the time.