# How do I understand ListCorrelate(contains $\{k_L,k_R\}$) when it works for 2-dimensional data?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

Two months ago, I asked a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58928/how-to-understand-the-process-of-listcorrelate-when-it-in-two-dimensional-condit)

And @nikie give me a solution:

> The intuitive way to understand `ListCorrelate` is that the kernel is "moved" to every position in the array, and the sum of the products between the kernel values and the array values at that position is stored in the output array:

I make a graphic to show this process as shown below:

> [image: the process]

However, I cannot understand this *built-in* function (contain $\{K_L,K_R\}$) when it works for 2-dimensional data.

For example,

$\{K_L,K_R\}=\{2,2\}$

```
ListCorrelate[
  {{x, y, z}, {u, v, w}}, 
  {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i,j, k, l}},
  {2, 2}]
```

> [image: result]

$\{K_L,K_R\}=\{2,3\}$ or $\{K_L,K_R\}=\{1,3\}$ or $\{K_L,K_R\}=\{-1,3\}$

According this result, I figure the picture:

> [image: diagram]

However, I cannot find the regulation, namely, how does `ListCorrelate` pad?

#### Update

Thanks for @DumpsterDoofus's solution, I know how the `ListCorrelate` work in 1-dimensional data when it contains ${k_L,k_R}$ *(as shown below*)

**the `ListCorrelate` work in 1-dimensional data when it contains $\{k_L,k_R\}$**

[image: one-dimensional case]

And now my main *confusion* is `ListCorrelate` works in *2-dimensional* data.

Is there a analogous graphic to show the process in 2-dimensional data?

Comment: Why did you get rid of your reputation? Are you going to wind up your account?

Comment: @Artes I just wanna share the points to people that ever help me.

Comment: It's all right, but a bit original to offer nine or so of the highest bounties in three days. This is why I'm curious.

Comment: @Artes I have not use Mathematica for 3 years. And very happy to learn much from here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

$K_L$ and $K_R$ represent *positions* in the kernel, specifically the positions of the kernel elements that overlap the first and last array elements. Here's an example showing the correlation of a 5×5 array with a 2×3 kernel, with each element of the result showing the overlapping kernel position. The array is in red and the kernel in grey. Here we are using the default "no-overhang" values `KL={1,1}` and `KR={-1,-1}`  (note that the positions are lists of length 2, as we are specifying a position in a 2D kernel. When we use `KL=1` that's just a shorthand for `KL={1,1}`)

[image]

Referring to the image above, we can see that in the top left corner, the kernel element `{1,1}` (KL) overlaps the top left element of the array. And in the bottom right corner the kernel element `{-1,-1}` (KR) overlaps the bottom right element of the array.

Now suppose we want a 2D correlation where the kernel overhangs by one element on the left hand side. Like this:

[image]

What should KL and KR be to get this? Look at the top left corner - the kernel element `{1,2}` is overlapping the top left element of the array, so we need `KL={1,2}`. And in the bottom right corner kernel element `{-1,-1}` overlaps the bottom right array element so we still have `KR={-1,-1}`.

Hopefully it will be no surprise that `KL=-1, KR=1` gives "maximal overhang" on all sides. This is shorthand for `KL={-1,-1}` and `KR={1,1}`, so the kernel element `{-1,-1}` overlaps in the top left and element `{1,1}` overlaps in the bottom right:

[image]

The padding option just determines how to deal with the parts of the kernel that hang outside of the array. You can imagine the array surrounded by zeros or by copies of itself (the default "periodic" padding) or whatever other values you specify. But for understanding KL and KR forget the padding and just look at which kernel elements overlap the first and last array elements.

Comment: Wow,+2, this solution is what I have been looking for.Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 5):

It becomes slightly easier if you look at 1-dimensional data first. Here's an example:

```
KER = Table[k[i], {i, 5}];
LIST = Table[l[i], {i, 8}];
ListCorrelate[KER, LIST, {2, 4}]
```

which produces:

```
{k[2] l[1] + k[3] l[2] + k[4] l[3] + k[5] l[4] + k[1] l[8], 
 k[1] l[1] + k[2] l[2] + k[3] l[3] + k[4] l[4] + k[5] l[5], 
 k[1] l[2] + k[2] l[3] + k[3] l[4] + k[4] l[5] + k[5] l[6], 
 k[1] l[3] + k[2] l[4] + k[3] l[5] + k[4] l[6] + k[5] l[7], 
 k[1] l[4] + k[2] l[5] + k[3] l[6] + k[4] l[7] + k[5] l[8], 
 k[5] l[1] + k[1] l[5] + k[2] l[6] + k[3] l[7] + k[4] l[8]}
```

To understand this output it helps to introduce some notation: given a list $l$ and a kernel $k$ of length $M$, define

$$F(j)=\sum_{\ell=1}^M k_{\ell}l_{\ell+j}$$

where the subscripts are interpreted modulo the length of the corresponding list. We then have

$$\text{ListCorrelate}\left[k,l,\{K_L,K_R\}\right]=\{F(-K_L+1),F(-K_L+2),...,F(K_R)\}.$$

In short, it is a partial cyclic correlation; $K_L$ determines how far to the *left* the correlation hangs, $K_R$ determines how far *right* the correlation hangs, and the resulting list has $K_L+K_R$ elements.

In particular, we have the following identity:

$$\text{ListCorrelate}\left[k,l\right]=\text{ListCorrelate}\left[k,l,\{1,M\}\right]$$

which relates the default behavior of `ListCorrelate` with the behavior with overhang lengths specified.

Comment: Firstly ,thanks for your solution, I know how the `ListCorrelate` work in 1-dimensional when it contains $\{k_L,k_R\}$, and now my mainly confusion is `ListCorrelate` works in 2-dimensional .

Comment: @ShutaoTang: See Simon Wood's answer for an explanation of the 2D case.

Comment: OK, @DumpsterDoofus I got it.:)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to understand the *built-in* function when it contains $\{K_L,K_R\}$

For the example you mention,

$\{K_L,K_R\}=\{2,2\}$

```
ListCorrelate[
  {{x, y, z}, {u, v, w}}, 
  {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i,j, k, l}},
  {2, 2}]
```

The best way is to split it up in simpler `ListCorrelate` functions.

```
ker = {{x, y, z}, {u, v, w}}
list = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}}
```

first row of the outcome is generated by starting with $K_L$ which means to start with `ker[[2]]` , at the position in `list` after skipping the first correlation of `ker[[1]]` (in case of a kernel with length 3, this means to start at `list` position 4). This can easily be shown with:

```
Total@
   (Flatten@      
      {
       ListCorrelate[ker[[2]], list[[1, {4, 1, 2}]]], 
       ListCorrelate[ker[[1]], list[[3, {4, 1, 2}]]]
      })

Total@
   (Flatten@
      {
       ListCorrelate[ker[[2]], list[[1, {1, 2, 3}]]], 
       ListCorrelate[ker[[1]], list[[3, {1, 2, 3}]]]
       })

Total@
   (Flatten@
      {
       ListCorrelate[ker[[2]],list[[1, {2, 3, 4}]]], 
       ListCorrelate[ker[[1]],list[[3, {2, 3, 4}]]]
      })

Total@
   (Flatten@
      {
       ListCorrelate[ker[[2]], list[[1, {3, 4, 1}]]], 
       ListCorrelate[ker[[1]], list[[3, {3, 4, 1}]]]
      })
```

> > (* OUT *)
> >
> > d u + a v + b w + l x + i y + j z
> >
> > a u + b v + c w + i x + j y + k z
> >
> > b u + c v + d w + j x + k y + l z
> >
> > c u + d v + a w + k x + l y + i z

In this way you I hope can see how the 'list' and 'kernel' are rotated and can expand the example up until the last row which uses $K_R$ = 2, or again `ker[[2]]`.