# Confused about how Partition works

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

I have a problem about the `padding list` about `Partition` command. For instance,

```
Partition[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, 3, 1, {-2, 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> {{z, a, b}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, d, e}, {d, e, f}, {e, f, g}, {f,g, y}, {g, y, z}}
> ```

However, my understanding about `padding list` shown as below:

> [image]

Another example

```
Partition[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, 3, 3, {1, 1}]
```

> ```
>  {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}
> ```

My understanding:

> [image]

#### Question

Can someone give me a good explanation?

Comment: I tend to agree with you about what the expected output should be. I don't have an explanation unfortunately but look forward to reading one if someone can explain it.

Comment: Related: [(64925)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64925/121) (your own question)

Comment: I just want to add I really like the way you ask your questions!

Comment: @Kuba,Thanks, I am very happy to hear that:) I found gradually that the understanding of construct is very important for learnnig *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Example #1

Let me make your example a bit smaller for brevity:

```
Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 3, 1, {-2, 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> {{z, a, b}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, d, y}, {d, y, z}}
> ```

This is in effect:

```
PadRight[{a, b, c, d}, 7, {x, y, z}, 1]

Partition[%, 3, 1]
```

> ```
> {z, a, b, c, d, y, z}
>
> {{z, a, b}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, d, y}, {d, y, z}}
> ```

Think instead:

[image]
+
[image]
Equals
[image]

#### Example #2

The documentation states:

[image]

Critical to your example is: "appear at ***or after*** position k<sub>R</sub> in the last sublist."

Therefore in this case it does not matter if k<sub>R</sub> is any of: `1`, `2`, `3`, `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, because each will be satisfied by:

```
{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}
```

`Partition` does not violate the cyclic order of the list.  For the output to be as you anticipated:

```
{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {f, a, b}}
```

The element `f` would have to be taken out of sequence; the next element should be `a`.

Comment: +1, Good explanation, thanks:), Could you give me a explanation about `another example`,See update of my question.

Comment: Ok,@Mr.Wizard, Today, I found that the understanding of the advanced usage of `Partition` is the basis of understanding the *built-in* function(like `ListCorrelate, ListConvolve` etc).

Comment: thanks. thinking in terms of how `PadRight` works explains it.

Comment: @ShutaoTang Please see my update and tell me if it is understandable.

Comment: OK,@Mr.Wizard, I got it:)

Comment: We need more threads like this for ListConvolve and friends :)