# Padding behavior

Tags: list-manipulation, padding

Why does `ArrayPad[Range[7], 4, Padding -> {1, 2, 3}]` return `{2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 1}`?

I expect it to return `{3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 1}`, what am I missing?

Comment: The details on how padding is performed are explained in the docs for [`PadLeft[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadLeft.html#27189) and [`PadRight[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html#18470). `ArrayPad[]` behaves consistently with these two. For more clarity, compare `PadLeft[Range[7], 11, {1, 2, 3}]` and `PadLeft[{}, 11, {1, 2, 3}]` (and analogously for `PadRight[]`).

Comment: I found in documentation: "With padding {Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2],\[Ellipsis],Subscript[x, s]}, cyclic repetitions of the Subscript[x, i] are effectively laid down and then the list is superimposed on top of them, with the last element of the list lying on an occurrence of Subscript[x, s]." That's so unobvious and inconvinient I feel!

Comment: Related: [(72740)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72740/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of prepending the elements cyclically (which would give the intuitive `{3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`, `PadLeft` (and thus `Arraypad`) effectively does

```
Block[
  {cyc = PadLeft[{}, 11, {1, 2, 3}] (*cyclic repetitions laid down*)},
  cyc[[-7 ;;]] = Range[7] (*list is superimposed on top of them*);
  cyc
]
PadLeft[Range[7], 11, {1, 2, 3}] == %
```

> {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}
>
> True

as described in the documentation

> With padding $\left\{x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_s\right\}$, cyclic repetitions of the $x_i$ are effectively laid down and then the list is superimposed on top of them, with the last element of the list lying on an occurrence of $x_s$.

Or more in general

```
myPadLeft[list_, n_, padding_] := Block[
  {cyc = PadLeft[{}, n, padding]},
  cyc[[-Length@list ;;]] = list;
  cyc
]
```

And another way of thinking about it

```
myPadLeft2[list_, n_, padding_] := PadLeft[{}, n, padding][[;; -Length@list - 1]]~Join~list
```