# ArrayPad unexpected changing of order

Tags: list-manipulation

If I pad an array with two columns on the left the order of the columns is reversed depending on the length of the row of the padded array. I don't think this is normal, but if it is, what is the right way to do it without the reversing of the order?

Below is the MWE. The second argument says: no padding on top, none on bottom, none on the right, two on the left. The third specifies what should be padded. Notice how the order of `z` and `y` changes in the result.

I am on Mathematica 10.1.0.0

````
ArrayPad[{{x}}, {{0, 0}, {2, 0}}, {y, z}]
Out={{z, y, x}}

ArrayPad[{{x, x}}, {{0, 0}, {2, 0}}, {y, z}]
Out={{y, z, x, x}}

ArrayPad[{{x, x, x}}, {{0, 0}, {2, 0}}, {y, z}]
Out={{z, y, x, x, x}}
```
````

Comment: I'm not sure why but the padding seems to go rightward and then rolls over onto the left of `x`. See this: `ArrayPad[{{x}}, 3, Range[6]] // MatrixForm` . Docs say this: `{Subscript[c, 1],Subscript[c, 2],\[Ellipsis]} cyclic repetition of constants Subscript[c, 1],\[Ellipsis]`

Comment: Behavior persists in 12.1. This smells like a bug to me: the weirdness is only for left-padding, and it appears to rotate the constant padding list right by the length of the row. I fail to come up with any justification for this.

Comment: Related: [(72740)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72740/121), [(209608)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/209608/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a function that gives the desired output:

```
ClearAll[arrayPad]
arrayPad = ArrayPad[#, {{0, 0}, {#3, 0}}, PadRight[#2, #3 + Length@#[[1]], #2]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{Grid[Prepend[{#, {y, z}, 2,
     arrayPad[#, {y, z}, 2]} & /@ ({ ConstantArray[x, #]} & /@ Range[4]), 
    {"a", "padding", "m", "arrayPad[a,padding,m]"}], Dividers -> All],
  Grid[Prepend[{#, {y, z, w}, 3, 
       arrayPad[#, {y, z, w}, 3]} & /@ ({ ConstantArray[x, #]} & /@ Range[4]), 
    {"a", "padding", "m", "arrayPad[a,padding,m]"}], Dividers -> All], 
  Grid[Prepend[{#, Range[4], 5,
       arrayPad[#, Range[4], 5]} & /@ ({ ConstantArray[x, #]} & /@ Range[4]),
    {"a", "padding", "m", "arrayPad[a,padding,m]"}], Dividers -> All]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

**How come ArrayPad changes the ordering?**

```
Trace @ ArrayPad[{{x}}, {{0, 0} , {2, 0}}, {y, z}]
```

> ```
> {ArrayPad[{{x}}, {{0, 0}, {2, 0}}, {y, z}], 
>  PadLeft[{{x}}, {1, 3}, {y, z}, {0, 0}], {{z, y, x}}}
> ```

[`PadLeft >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadLeft.html)

[image]

That is, `ArrayPad[{a}, {{0,0}, {m,0}}, padding]` behaves as if it takes `PadLeft[padding, m + Length[a], padding]` and replaces the last `Length[a]`  elements of this list with `a`. For the example in OP:

```
PadLeft[{y, z}, 2 + #, {y, z}] & /@ Range[3]
```

> ```
> { {z, y, z}, {y, z, y, z}, {z, y, z, y, z}}
> ```

whereas

```
PadRight[{y, z}, 2 + #, {y, z}] & /@ Range[3]
```

> ```
> {{y, z, y}, {y, z, y, z}, {y, z, y, z, y}}
> ```

In other words, `ArrayPad[a, {{0,0}, {m,0}}, padding]` behaves like the version of `arrayPad` above with `PadRight` replaced with `PadLeft`:

```
padding = Range[5];
pl = RandomInteger[{1, 10}]; 

And @@ (ArrayPad[{ConstantArray[x, #]}, {{0, 0}, {pl, 0}}, padding] === 
  ArrayPad[{ConstantArray[x, #]}, {{0, 0}, {pl, 0}},
    PadLeft[padding, pl + #, padding]] & /@ Range[10])
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Please let me know if you disagree with the closure.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, [Padding Behavior](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209608/padding-behavior) seems to be a duplicate. But  this question also asks  _**" what is the right way to do it without the reversing of the order"**_.

Answer (score 2):

A way without ArrayPad

```
Join[{y, z}, Map[x &, Range[4]]]
(* Out: {y, z, x, x, x, x} *)

PadRight[{y, z}, 10, x]
```